# How to compare html files in unix

Tags: unix, sh

I have two folders with huge number of HTML files and I want to compare each file and how to get the diff of each file using shell script/unix commands.

Example:
Directory 1:

```
1.html
2.html
3.html
```

Directory 2:

```
1.html
2.html
3.html..
```

I want to compare `1.html` in directory with `1.html` in `dir2`, and `2.html` with `2.html`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $1/*.html; do
fileName=$(basename "$file")

if [ ! -f $2/$fileName ]; then
    echo $fileName " not found! in "$2
else
    difLineCount=$(diff $file $2/$fileName | wc -l)
    if [ $difLineCount -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $file "is same " $2/$fileName;
    else 
       echo $file "is not same " $2/$fileName "." $difLineCount "lines are different"; 
       #diff $file $2/$fileName
    fi
fi
done

for file in $2/*.html; do
fileName=$(basename "$file")
    if [ ! -f $1/$fileName ]; then
            echo $fileName " not found! in "$1
    fi
done
```

Ex :

```
user@host:/tmp$ ./test.sh Directory_1 Directory_2
Directory_1/1.html is same  Directory_2/1.html
Directory_1/2.html is same  Directory_2/2.html
Directory_1/3.html is not same  Directory_2/3.html . 4 lines are different
4.html  not found! in Directory_2
5.html  not found! in Directory_1


user@host:/tmp$ ls -alrt Directory_1/
total 20
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    6 Ağu 11 13:28 1.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    6 Ağu 11 13:28 2.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    6 Ağu 11 13:28 3.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    0 Ağu 11 13:41 4.html
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Ağu 11 13:41 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 user user 4096 Ağu 11 13:48 ..


user@host:/tmp$ ls -alrt Directory_2/
total 20
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    7 Ağu 11 13:28 3.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    6 Ağu 11 13:28 2.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    6 Ağu 11 13:28 1.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    0 Ağu 11 13:44 5.html
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Ağu 11 13:44 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 user user 4096 Ağu 11 13:48 ..
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. How would i get different lines content?

Comment: you should uncomment "#diff $file $2/$fileName" in the code,

Answer (score 0):

You can use comm command to compare sorted files. This might be the actual solution you are looking for.

Syntax: `comm file1 file2`

Compare sorted files FILE1 and FILE2 line-by-line.
With no options, comm produces three-column output. Column one contains lines unique to FILE1, column two contains lines unique to FILE2, and column three contains lines common to both files. Each of these columns can be suppressed individually with options.

**Keep the comm command in a loop such that it compares all the files in your required directories.**

**If you want to compare files one by one manually:**

You need to use diff command to display line-by-line difference between two files.

Syntax: `diff path/FILE1 path/FILE2`

You can use --changed-group-format and --unchanged-group-format options to filter required data.

Following three options can use to select the relevant group for each option:

'%<' get lines from FILE1
'%>' get lines from FILE2
'' (empty string) for removing lines from both files.

Example: `diff --changed-group-format="%<" --unchanged-group-format="" file1 file2`

You can get a clear-cut visual difference between two text files using the command sdiff:

Syntax: `sdiff path/file1 path/file2`

If you have vim editor installed 
use: `vim -d file1 file2`